# Setting a minimum height in a TabLayout is ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-tablayout

I have the following `TabLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/my_selector"
    />
```

I set in the tabs the following layout as custom view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/red"

>


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="FOO"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

And have set it as follows:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null)));  
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null)));
```

Problem:
I can not control the height of the `TabLayout`. It wraps the content while I have set a `minHeight`.
What am I messing up here?